# Debugger does not stop on breakpoint when using testNG and Surefire

Tags: spring, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, testng

I have added testNG to my pom file and created couple of tests.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceConfig.class})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class TrackPersistenceServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {
        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TrackPersistenceServiceTest.class);
        @Autowired
        TrackPersistenceService trackPersistenceService;

    //    @Test(groups = {"dev"})
        public void thatTracksListCanBeUpdated() throws Exception {
            EntitiesCreatedEvent event = trackPersistenceService.updateTracksList();
            assertTrue( event.getNumOfCreatedEntities()==12 );
        }
```

When I am running the tests with debug mode using:

```
call mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=6666 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" test -Dgroups=dev
```

The surefire starts and is waiting on port 6666.

**The problem:** is that though I am connecting to it with intellij remote debugger. It executes the tests but the debugger does not stop at the breakpoints.

I am sure the breakpoints are on code that is being executed.

I added to pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Didnt add the surefire plugin to the pom based on [this](http://testng.org/doc/maven.html) tutorial

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually did was to clear the cache.

Though the docs mention File|invalidate cache I could not find and under that menu. 
I found it using the find everywhere.

I also update the intellij version.